# In Ajax how to show validation of the input that the user interacts with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In Ajax I just want to show the validation of the input that the user interacts with. Not the show all validations. In my script if you write anything to any input you will get all inputs validations in the same time. Its show all validations.

I mean if you write 3 in fullname input then validations says: *"Fullname must be alphanumerical"* but in the same time also show username, email and password validations too. It shows all the validations. I try to prevent this thing but can't catch the logical vision. How can I achieve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#register-form").keyup(function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "registercontrol.php",
                data: {
                    fullname: fullname,
                    username: username,
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {
                    
                    $('.hidden').show();
                    $('#result').html(result);

                    $("#vfullname").html("");
                    $("#fullname").removeClass();
                    $("#fullname").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");

                    $("#vusername").html("");
                    $("#username").removeClass();
                    $("#username").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");

                    $("#vemail").html("");
                    $("#email").removeClass();
                    $("#email").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");

                    $("#vpassword").html("");
                    $("#password").removeClass();
                    $("#password").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");

                    if (result.fni) {
                        $("#vfullname").html(result['fni']);
                        $("#vfullname").removeClass();
                        $("#vfullname").addClass("text-info");
                        $("#fullname").removeClass();
                        $("#fullname").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
                    }
                    if (result.fnw) {
                        $("#vfullname").html(result['fnw']);
                        $("#vfullname").removeClass();
                        $("#vfullname").addClass("text-warning");
                        $("#fullname").removeClass();
                        $("#fullname").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-warning");
                    }
                    
                    if (result.uni) {
                        $("#vusername").html(result['uni']);
                        $("#vusername").removeClass();                      
                        $("#vusername").addClass("text-info");
                        $("#username").removeClass();
                        $("#username").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
                    }
                    if (result.unw) {
                        $("#vusername").html(result['unw']);
                        $("#vusername").removeClass();                      
                        $("#vusername").addClass("text-warning");
                        $("#username").removeClass();
                        $("#username").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-warning");
                    } 
                    if (result.une) {
                        $("#vusername").html(result['une']);
                        $("#vusername").removeClass();                      
                        $("#vusername").addClass("text-danger");
                        $("#username").removeClass();
                        $("#username").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-danger");
                    }

                    if (result.mi) {
                        $("#vemail").html(result['mi']);
                        $("#vemail").removeClass();                     
                        $("#vemail").addClass("text-info");
                        $("#email").removeClass();
                        $("#email").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
                    }
                    if (result.mw) {
                        $("#vemail").html(result['mw']);
                        $("#vemail").removeClass();                     
                        $("#vemail").addClass("text-warning");
                        $("#email").removeClass();
                        $("#email").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-warning");
                    }
                    if (result.me) {
                        $("#vemail").html(result['me']);
                        $("#vemail").removeClass();                     
                        $("#vemail").addClass("text-danger");
                        $("#email").removeClass();
                        $("#email").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-danger");
                    }

                    if (result.pwi) {
                        $("#vpassword").html(result['pwi']);
                        $("#vpassword").removeClass();                      
                        $("#vpassword").addClass("text-info");
                        $("#password").removeClass();
                        $("#password").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
                    } 
                    if (result.pww) {
                        $("#vpassword").html(result['pww']);
                        $("#vpassword").removeClass();                      
                        $("#vpassword").addClass("text-warning");
                        $("#password").removeClass();
                        $("#password").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-warning");
                    }                            
                }
            });         
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: You have so many repetitions of code which can replaced by few lines to archive the same results.

Comment: You do not even need to an `ajax` request to do validation on the front end. You are define all your validations how you want your fullname to be filled on the frontend. Instead of doing `100's` of ajax calls to back end on a `keyup` function,

Comment: So what should I do then? @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Read more about how to data validation like `Fullname must be alphanumerical` use patterns and `regEx` in your `inputs`. Read about it here: [Pattern In Input MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)

Comment: Added an event listener to each of the input fields, when there is a value update, you can  do some logic to decide if it is valid or not. Before you submit your form, check all those values are valid, and if so, proceed.

Comment: Also if you are wanting feedback on if an email or username has already been taken, in those events, query the api each time there is an update to those two fields to see if they are taken or not. Possibly only do the email query once you do regex to determine if it follows an email format or not. This would involve checking for a '@' for example.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answers. Now I will try to do some regex for other inputs before check username and email already in use or not.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I have fixed based on your recommendations and it works. Thank you so much for your help. I answered my own question. Would you look at my Script. Do you see anything unnecessary or a place that needs to be optimized?

Comment: @Ulrich you calling .removeClass so two times in your if conditions. You can just call it once and do the same thing .html as well. Just do it once only when you key up. Or in your if conditions. Not on both. Rest all looks good if all is working for you :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Thanks for advice again. I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is much simpler answer for you by using `this` and use of `.attr` instead of doing multiple `keyup` functions i am only doing one and using `if` conditions to match `.attr` of input i am typing in.

I have also assigned unique class `.validate_input` to all inputs to do `keyup` function on that and then i checking by this `.attr` to get the typed input `.val()`

Run snippet below to check all validation is working nicely as you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //RegEx
  var fullnameregex = /^([a-zA-Z\-_ ’'‘ÆÐƎƏƐƔĲŊŒẞÞǷȜæðǝəɛɣĳŋœĸſßþƿȝĄƁÇĐƊĘĦĮƘŁØƠŞȘŢȚŦŲƯY̨Ƴąɓçđɗęħįƙłøơşșţțŧųưy̨ƴÁÀÂÄǍĂĀÃÅǺĄÆǼǢƁĆĊĈČÇĎḌĐƊÐÉÈĖÊËĚĔĒĘẸƎƏƐĠĜǦĞĢƔáàâäǎăāãåǻąæǽǣɓćċĉčçďḍđɗðéèėêëěĕēęẹǝəɛġĝǧğģɣĤḤĦIÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨĮỊĲĴĶƘĹĻŁĽĿʼNŃN̈ŇÑŅŊÓÒÔÖǑŎŌÕŐỌØǾƠŒĥḥħıíìiîïǐĭīĩįịĳĵķƙĸĺļłľŀŉńn̈ňñņŋóòôöǒŏōõőọøǿơœŔŘŖŚŜŠŞȘṢẞŤŢṬŦÞÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨŰŮŲỤƯẂẀŴẄǷÝỲŶŸȲỸƳŹŻŽẒŕřŗſśŝšşșṣßťţṭŧþúùûüǔŭūũűůųụưẃẁŵẅƿýỳŷÿȳỹƴźżžẓ]+)$/;
  var usernameregex = /^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/;
  var emailregex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
  var passwordregex = /^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%&]).*$/;

  //Input Validations
  $('.validate_inputs').keyup(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'fullname') {
      if (!fullnameregex.test($(this).val())) {
        $("#vfullname").html("Please enter a valid name.");
        $("#vfullname").removeClass();
        $("#vfullname").addClass("text-info");
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
      } else {
        $("#vfullname").html("");
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");
      }
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'username') {
      if (!usernameregex.test($(this).val())) {
        $("#vusername").html("Please enter a valid username.");
        $("#vusername").removeClass();
        $("#vusername").addClass("text-info");
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
      } else {
        $("#vusername").html("");
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");
      }
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'email') {
      if (!emailregex.test($(this).val())) {
        $("#vemail").html("Please enter a valid email");
        $("#vemail").removeClass();
        $("#vemail").addClass("text-info");
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
      } else {
        $("#vemail").html("");
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");
      }
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'password') {
      if (!passwordregex.test($(this).val())) {
        $("#vpassword").html("The password must contain at least one upper and lower case character, a number and a special character.");
        $("#vpassword").removeClass();
        $("#vpassword").addClass("text-info");
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
      } else {
        $("#vpassword").html("");
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");
      }
    }
  });


  //Ajax Validations
  $("#register-form").keyup(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "registercontrol.php",
      data: {
        fullname: fullname,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {

        if (result.une) {
          $("#vusername").html(result['une']);
          $("#vusername").removeClass();
          $("#vusername").addClass("text-danger");
          $("#username").removeClass();
          $("#username").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-danger");
        }

        if (result.me) {
          $("#vemail").html(result['me']);
          $("#vemail").removeClass();
          $("#vemail").addClass("text-danger");
          $("#email").removeClass();
          $("#email").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-danger");
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  Name <input type="text" class="validate_inputs" id="fullname" />
  <div id="vfullname"></div>
  Username <input type="text" class="validate_inputs" id="username" />
  <div id="vusername"></div>
  Email <input type="text" class="validate_inputs" id="email" />
  <div id="vemail"></div>
  Password <input type="email" class="validate_inputs" id="password" />
  <div id="vpassword"></div>

  <button id="register-form">Submit</button>


</div>
```

Comment: Wow, its really impressive much look better, more optimized. Thanks for your help. You are really @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @Ulrich Glad that i was able to help you again :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

With help of [AlwaysHelping](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13669048/alwayshelping).

I made some the validations on Javascript side that do not require database connection and Php and I processed each one separately in the `.keyup` function, so only the input that was actually interacting was giving the validations error and resolved other Ajax-requiring verification in a single Ajax call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //Input Validations
        $("#fullname").keyup(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
            $("#vfullname").html("");
            $("#fullname").removeClass();
            $("#fullname").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");
            var fullnameregex = /^([a-zA-Z\-_ ’'‘ÆÐƎƏƐƔĲŊŒẞÞǷȜæðǝəɛɣĳŋœĸſßþƿȝĄƁÇĐƊĘĦĮƘŁØƠŞȘŢȚŦŲƯY̨Ƴąɓçđɗęħįƙłøơşșţțŧųưy̨ƴÁÀÂÄǍĂĀÃÅǺĄÆǼǢƁĆĊĈČÇĎḌĐƊÐÉÈĖÊËĚĔĒĘẸƎƏƐĠĜǦĞĢƔáàâäǎăāãåǻąæǽǣɓćċĉčçďḍđɗðéèėêëěĕēęẹǝəɛġĝǧğģɣĤḤĦIÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨĮỊĲĴĶƘĹĻŁĽĿʼNŃN̈ŇÑŅŊÓÒÔÖǑŎŌÕŐỌØǾƠŒĥḥħıíìiîïǐĭīĩįịĳĵķƙĸĺļłľŀŉńn̈ňñņŋóòôöǒŏōõőọøǿơœŔŘŖŚŜŠŞȘṢẞŤŢṬŦÞÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨŰŮŲỤƯẂẀŴẄǷÝỲŶŸȲỸƳŹŻŽẒŕřŗſśŝšşșṣßťţṭŧþúùûüǔŭūũűůųụưẃẁŵẅƿýỳŷÿȳỹƴźżžẓ]+)$/;
            if (!fullnameregex.test(fullname)) {
                $("#vfullname").html("Please enter a valid name.");
                $("#vfullname").removeClass();
                $("#vfullname").addClass("text-info");
                $("#fullname").removeClass();
                $("#fullname").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
            }
        });

        $("#username").keyup(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            $("#vusername").html("");
            $("#username").removeClass();
            $("#username").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");
            var usernameregex = /^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/;
            if (!usernameregex.test(username)) {
                $("#vusername").html("Please enter a valid username.");
                $("#vusername").removeClass();
                $("#vusername").addClass("text-info");
                $("#username").removeClass();
                $("#username").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
            }
        });

        $("#email").keyup(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            $("#vemail").html("");
            $("#email").removeClass();
            $("#email").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");
            var emailregex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
            if (!emailregex.test(email)) {
                $("#vemail").html("Please enter a valid email");
                $("#vemail").removeClass();
                $("#vemail").addClass("text-info");
                $("#email").removeClass();
                $("#email").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
            }
        });

        $("#password").keyup(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            $("#vpassword").html("");
            $("#password").removeClass();
            $("#password").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");
            var passwordregex = /^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%&]).*$/;
            if (!passwordregex.test(password)) {
                $("#vpassword").html("The password must contain at least one upper and lower case character, a number and a special character.");
                $("#vpassword").removeClass();
                $("#vpassword").addClass("text-info");
                $("#password").removeClass();
                $("#password").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
            }
        });

        //Ajax Validations
        $("#register-form").keyup(function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var password = $('#password').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "registercontrol.php",
                data: {
                    fullname: fullname,
                    username: username,
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {

                    if (result.une) {
                        $("#vusername").html(result['une']);
                        $("#vusername").removeClass();
                        $("#vusername").addClass("text-danger");
                        $("#username").removeClass();
                        $("#username").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-danger");
                    }

                    if (result.me) {
                        $("#vemail").html(result['me']);
                        $("#vemail").removeClass();
                        $("#vemail").addClass("text-danger");
                        $("#email").removeClass();
                        $("#email").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-danger");
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    }); 
</script>
```